# How to add large file (in GB) in Xcode project?

Tags: postgis, mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles

I am working with Mapbox Framework. I have generated MBTiles file which I want to use in my project (for iPhones and iPads) but that file is having size of 3GB (which I can't use in project). When I added that file in project, it created a build of 3.29GB.

When I gave reference of that file too, created build in GBs.

Is there any way that I can use that file in my Xcode project without increasing build size?